# w32tm /monitor VS w32tm /monitor /computers:

Tags: windows-xp, ntp

Let's say I have a computer called...StpdPrblm.  When I open a command prompt window (domain user, local administrator) and run "w32tm /monitor" I get a good response from all 70 of my domain controllers.  But when I run "w32tm /monitor /computers:StpdPrblm.domain.corp", I get the following output:

- StpdPrblm.domain.corp [error 0x8007277C]

I get the same response from StpdPrblm no matter how many computers I try to query using the /computers: flag.  What's going on?  Googling that error code was fantastically unhelpful.

edit: StpdPrblm is XP SP 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened command prompt and ran:
net time /setsntp:domain_name

And then rebooting seems to have fixed it.  Alternatively, the following can be executed to retstart the time service:
net stop w32time
net start w32time

Answer (score 0):

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.it.pool.ntp.org 1.it.pool.ntp.org 2.it.pool.ntp.org 3.it.pool.ntp.org"
net start w32time
w32tm /config /update
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

.BAT Sample File :https://gist.github.com/thedom85/dbeb58627adfb3d5c3af

I also recommend this program :http://www.timesynctool.com/